# numerical evaluation of an oscillatory integral

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Let $c=3, d=4, w=0.1$ and define
$$
f(s,w) = \exp \left(cs+d\sin(2ws)\right)\\
g(T) = \frac{1}{T} \int_{t=0}^{t=T} \int_{s=0}^{s=t} \frac{f(s,w)}{f(t,w)} dsdt
$$

I would like to graph $g(T)$. I tried several of the `NIntegrate` methods, but they seem to breakdown as T gets large.  I get the error, `Highly Oscillatory` and they are very slow.

Comment: Judging from your code references, I would *guess* that you're using Mathematica. As I don't see much in the way of Mathematical content, I would recommend that you ask over at [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). That said, try `f[s_] = Exp[3s+4Sin[0.2s]]; F[T_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[s]/f[t],{t,0,T},{s,0,t}]; Plot[F[T],{T,-1,3}]`.